# accordion menu jquery active menu

Tags: jquery, html

I have accordion menu width JQuery, it works well but I want to keep the selected menu active when I open it: exactly like this: http://www.3ds.com/fr/

This is what I did:

```
$(function() {
                $('#accordion > li').hover(
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    },
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                    }
                );
            });
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can I have the same animation 3ds site, I already had a code but all menus closes after mouseover and it moves.

Comment: To be clearer what I have change in my code to have an active menu on page load and a fixed width of the block

Comment: not clear at all what you want. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net with enough basic css and your code to show what issue is